# Write and get result for SOQL query using JAVA

Tags: java, salesforce, soql

how do I write a java program to query an object/table in salesforce and get results in csv?
I haven't found any clear instructions for the same on the internet.

Comment: Have you reviewed the [Salesforce API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm)? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has some default APIs that allow external systems interacting with a Salesforce org. Two examples of them are the SOAP API and the REST Api. Both APIs expose methods to interact with the Salesforce Org, allowing operations like creating, updating, deleting records and also querying.

You can use the SOAP Api (more precisely, the query method https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query.htm) to query the Salesforce database.

You can check this example from the SF documentation that walks you through a JAVA implementation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_walk_through_code.htm. Also, the rest of the documentation from that Salesforce site is full of Java examples that can help you.